# How can I find the Serial number on a Lenovo machine?

Tags: thinkpad, dmidecode

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkPad. How can I find the serial number on this machine without shutting down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the serial number of your machine by using `dmidecode`,

- For the system, which is likely what you want,

  ```bash
  sudo dmidecode -t system | grep Serial
  ```
- For the motherboard,

  ```bash
  sudo dmidecode -t baseboard | grep Serial
  ```